# How to bring down the fab in bottom app bar?

Tags: android, floating-action-button, bottomnavigationview, material-components-android, android-bottomappbar

Since `app:fabCradleVerticalOffset` cannot have a negative value, I couldn't find   a way to bring down the FAB component in bottom app bar.

Comment: this answer maybe solve your problem [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54044293/floatingactionbutton-too-high-over-bottomappbar?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: 48 dp didnt resolve my issue. Please let me know if there is any other solution